I am having a problem writing a .sql file from a .csv file in python
I need to write a .sql file that creates a table.
I am importing the .csv file using pandas:
import os
import pandas as pd

csv_directory = '/.../test/'

# Lecture des fichiers CSV et génération des requêtes SQL
sql_queries = []
for file in os.listdir(csv_directory):
  if file.endswith('.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_directory + file, header=None)  # Lecture du fichier CSV avec pandas
    table_name = file.split('.')[0]  # Utilisation du nom de fichier comme nom de table
    print (file)
    #print (table_name)
    #print (df)
    create_table_query = f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (code TEXT NOT NULL, valeur TEXT NULL, description TEXT,CONSTRAINT {table_name}_pk PRIMARY KEY (code));"
    insert_data_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (code, valeur, description) VALUES "
    insert_data_query += ', '.join([str(tuple(row)) for row in df.values]) + ';'
    sql_queries.append(create_table_query)
    sql_queries.append(insert_data_query)

# Écriture des requêtes SQL dans un fichier
with open('list.sql', 'w') as file:
    for query in sql_queries:
        file.write(query + '\n')

but I need :
('non_concerne','Non concerné(e)','information non possible ou non pertinente pour l''élément décrit')
instead of
('non_concerne','Non concerné(e)',"information non possible ou non pertinente pour l'élément décrit")

Python cannot handle the french apostrophe if the string is defined by single quotation marks. Consider replacing all single marks in the definition of strings '' with doubles "".
I think there might be a workaround with backslashes as well as an escape character, for example:
print('information non possible ou non pertinente pour l\'élément décrit')

gives:
information non possible ou non pertinente pour l'élément décrit

Whereas:
print('information non possible ou non pertinente pour l'élément décrit')

Gives an error since the string ends after the l:
File "/tmp/ipykernel_75916/2440330730.py", line 1
    print('information non possible ou non pertinente pour l'élément décrit')
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Edit 1: more specific answer with an example
I generated a .csv file that looks like this:

And the code to write the sql is here:
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("french.csv", sep = ";", header=None, encoding='latin1')
with open('list.sql', 'w') as file:
    for row in data.iterrows():
        for element in row[1].values:
            file.write(element + ';')
        file.write("\n")

In the sql file, the data is stored like this:
"non_concerne";"Non concerné(e)";"information non possible ou non pertinente pour l'élément décrit";

Did you try reading the file with latin1 encoding? As I said before, I think your problem lies with the string definition and the fact that you have a single quote in your string.

in my csv, all items have "" like  :  "non_concerne","Non concerné(e)","information non possible ou non pertinente pour l'élément décrit"

what about when you are importing the file? how does your dataframe look like?

dataframe look like : l'élément ,not lélément or l''élément

@pasqal check my update, if you could upload a section of the file that might help me give you a better answer

You can create a sql engine
  def conexion():
  #Read csv
  df_csv_directory=pd.read_csv("'/.../test/'")
  #create database
  database=create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
  #you add the tables you have in your csv
  df_csv_directory.to_sql('csv_directory',database,index=False)

You create te conexion
#check you tables 
conexion()
inspector = inspect(database)
print('Tablas: ', inspector.get_table_names(), '\n')
print('Columns:')
for column in inspector.get_columns('pedidos'):
print(column)

Import you need sqlalchemy you can install pip install SQLAlchemy and then import it
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, inspect, text 

example of how to make a query once the database has been created
query='''
    SELECT * from
    table_name
    
    '''
df=pd.read_sql(sql=text(query),con=database.connect())
print(df)


I need to generate .sql file, not directly in base, but thank you
